# For loop invalid character javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have issue in firefox 22 and IE (basic from win7) finds invalid character error in trivial for loops. Code works fine in Opera. Here is the trivial testcase:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
...
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   alert("ccc");
​}//INVALID CHARACTER IN THIS LINE
</script>
...
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "language" attribute (`<script language="javascript"`), I wonder if your problem could come from there, could you remove it for a quick check?

Comment: I'd personally suggest leaving out the attributes, and attribute-values, from the `script` tag. Also, the problem is an invisible character prior to the `}` in the last line ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LHdks/), look at the red bullet). Removing that character makes it work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LHdks/1/).

Comment: The `language` attribute has never been standardized and is obsolete as of HTML5. You should remove it. Also, HTML5 defaults script type to `text/javascript` so you can drop the type attribute as well (all browsers released in the last decade default scripting to JavaScript anyway so there are no backwards compatibility issues dropping it).

Comment: I wrote `<script>` as you said, same... also tried `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`... same.

Comment: Please ignore all these comments about the surrounding HTML. They are FUD and have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Phrogz: honestly? Because it felt like a cheat of an answer ("here's your problem, press delete"); basically it's a typo question (the only interesting part comes from the *origin* of the typo, which you addressed in your own answer, but I did not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one or more bad whitespace characters in your source code, *likely* the result of copy/pasting from a web page. Re-type the content in a new file by hand, and watch the problem disappear.

Alternatively, delete every space/tab and return character from the file and re-type them.

In this case, the bad character comes before the `}` on the line you indicate. Place the cursor before that character and press delete/backspace and notice that nothing seems to happen. You have just deleted the bad character.

(Want proof? Copy/paste the content of the script block above into http://jsfiddle.net and notice the bright red bullet that appears.)

Comment: *"... re-type by hand [in a plain-text editor] ..."* - you'd be surprised how *verbose* you often need to be :)

Comment: I encoded it in ANSI in npp, some nebulous chars showed up, deleted them, then encoded it back to utf-8 without bom, and it is working. Page was not pasted, it's made in DW from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste you code into **jsbeautifier.org** 
you will see your problem right away. It is maked in red.